# How to use Django (Class)Views for a particular <div> in the template (through Ajax) ;I am integrating django-chatrooms app in my project

Tags: ajax, django, class, templates, chatroom

I am relatively new to Django . I want to integrate Django-chatrooms(https://github.com/qubird/django-chatrooms) App into my project . 
This app has 3 different URLs (1.Available-ChatRooms list 2.Set-guestname/Login 3.Room(actual chat interface)) . 
But I want to make all these 3 features (Join room,set guestname/login and chatWindow)available to the user at the same URL (which is my Project HomePage).So I will be doing it through Ajax .

I need to call 3 Class Views from the App ; This is the corresponding URL's and views files of the app :

## urls.py

```
#encoding=utf8

from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, patterns

from . import views
from .utils.decorators import room_check_access
from .ajax import chat

urlpatterns = patterns('chatrooms',
    # room views
    url(r'^rooms/$',
    views.RoomsListView.as_view(),
    name="rooms_list"),
    url(r'^room/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$',
    room_check_access(views.RoomView.as_view()),
    name="room_view"),
    url(r'^setguestname/$',
    views.GuestNameView.as_view(),
    name="set_guestname"),

    # ajax requests
    url(r'^get_messages/', chat.ChatView().get_messages),
    url(r'^send_message/', chat.ChatView().send_message),
    url(r'^get_latest_msg_id/', chat.ChatView().get_latest_message_id),
    url(r'^get_users_list/$', chat.ChatView().get_users_list),
    url(r'^notify_users_list/$', chat.ChatView().notify_users_list),
)
```

## Views.py

```
#encoding=utf8

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, FormView

from .utils.auth import get_login_url
from .forms.guest import GuestNameForm
from .models import Room


class RoomsListView(ListView):
    """View to show the list of rooms available """
    context_object_name = "rooms"
    template_name = "chatrooms/rooms_list.html"
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
    filters = {}
    if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
        filters['allow_anonymous_access'] = True
    return Room.objects.filter(**filters)


class RoomView(DetailView):
    """View for the single room """
    model = Room
    context_object_name = 'room'
    template_name = "chatrooms/room.html"


class GuestNameView(FormView):
    """Shows the form to choose a guest name to anonymous users """
    form_class = GuestNameForm
    template_name = 'chatrooms/guestname_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update(super(GuestNameView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs))
    room_slug = self.request.GET.get('room_slug')
    next = ''
    if room_slug:
        next = reverse('room_view', kwargs={'slug': room_slug})
    kwargs['login_url'] = get_login_url(next)
    return kwargs

    def get_initial(self):
    init = super(GuestNameView, self).get_initial()
    room_slug = self.request.GET.get('room_slug')
    if room_slug:
        init.update(room_slug=room_slug)
    return init

    def form_valid(self, form):
    guest_name = form.cleaned_data.get('guest_name')
    room_slug = form.cleaned_data.get('room_slug')
    self.request.session['guest_name'] = guest_name
    if room_slug:
        redirect_url = reverse('room_view', kwargs={'slug': room_slug})
    else:
        redirect_url = reverse('rooms_list')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

## My Home View containing home.html template (where I want to integrate Chat)

```
def home_view(request):
    site = Site.objects.get_current()
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'user':request.user,'data':request.POST , 'site':site})
```

### How do I receive a template with it's context and append it to my div as an HTML ? (For eg . I want that whenever I call GuestNameView through Ajax, it should return me a template with the context rendered which I will append as HTML to my div at project home )